# create a new variable based on multiple conditions in r

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I do not know how to create a new variable based on multiple conditions.

The example can interprete my problem.

There are 3 main variables.

`id` means people. The same `id` means same people.

`date` means the date that access to hospital.

`outcome` means if a person have a specific disease. `1` means sick and `0` means no disease.

```
df = data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4),
  date = c('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01',
           '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01',
           '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01',
           '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'),
  outcome = c(0,0,1,1, 0,1,0,0, 1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0)
) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 16 × 3
      id date       outcome
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>
 1     1 2013-01-01       0
 2     1 2014-01-01       0
 3     1 2015-01-01       1
 4     1 2016-01-01       1
 5     2 2013-01-01       0
 6     2 2014-01-01       1
 7     2 2015-01-01       0
 8     2 2016-01-01       0
 9     3 2013-01-01       1
10     3 2014-01-01       1
11     3 2015-01-01       0
12     3 2016-01-01       0
13     4 2013-01-01       0
14     4 2014-01-01       0
15     4 2015-01-01       0
16     4 2016-01-01       0
```

I want to create a new variable `time.to.event` which means the time difference between the date of first accident and date of first time access to hospital.

for example:

for `id = 1`, the date of first accident is `2015-01-01`;
the date of first time access to hospital is `2013-01-01`.
`time.to.event` should be `730` (`2015-01-01` minus `2013-01-01`).

for `id = 2`, the date of first accident is `2014-01-01`;
the date of first time access to hospital is `2013-01-01`.
`time.to.event` should be `365` (`2014-01-01` minus `2013-01-01`).

for `id = 3`, the date of first accident is `2013-01-01`;
the date of first time access to hospital is `2013-01-01`.
`time.to.event` should be `0` (`2013-01-01` minus `2013-01-01`).

for `id = 4`, there is no date of first accident.
`time.to.event` should be `1095` (`max(date)` minus `min(date)`).

I have tried the code below but failed.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time.to.event = 
           case_when(sum(outcome) == 0 ~max(date) - min(date),
                     sum(outcome) != 0 ~ first(date[outcome == 1]) - min(date)))
```

The final data should like this:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
      id date       outcome time.to.event
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1 2013-01-01       0           730
 2     1 2014-01-01       0           730
 3     1 2015-01-01       1           730
 4     1 2016-01-01       1           730
 5     2 2013-01-01       0           365
 6     2 2014-01-01       1           365
 7     2 2015-01-01       0           365
 8     2 2016-01-01       0           365
 9     3 2013-01-01       1             0
10     3 2014-01-01       1             0
11     3 2015-01-01       0             0
12     3 2016-01-01       0             0
13     4 2013-01-01       0          1095    
14     4 2014-01-01       0          1095    
15     4 2015-01-01       0          1095  
16     4 2016-01-01       0          1095
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by id, and subtract the minimum date from the minimum date where outcome==1; I've implemented in a helper function, `f`

```
f <- function(x,o) {
  if(1 %in% o) min(x[o==1]) - min(x)
  else max(x) -  min(x)
}
```

Now, just apply the function to `df` by `id`

```
group_by(df, id) %>% mutate(days = f(date,outcome))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
# Groups:   id [4]
      id date       outcome days     
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl> <drtn>   
 1     1 2013-01-01       0  730 days
 2     1 2014-01-01       0  730 days
 3     1 2015-01-01       1  730 days
 4     1 2016-01-01       1  730 days
 5     2 2013-01-01       0  365 days
 6     2 2014-01-01       1  365 days
 7     2 2015-01-01       0  365 days
 8     2 2016-01-01       0  365 days
 9     3 2013-01-01       1    0 days
10     3 2014-01-01       1    0 days
11     3 2015-01-01       0    0 days
12     3 2016-01-01       0    0 days
13     4 2013-01-01       0 1095 days
14     4 2014-01-01       0 1095 days
15     4 2015-01-01       0 1095 days
16     4 2016-01-01       0 1095 days
```

Comment: Thanks @langtang. I apologize that I missed a situation when a person does not have an ending event (see id = 4 in the edited example). I tried to do the calculation with case_when, but it failed.

Comment: see  my update @zhiweili

Answer (score 2):

We may wrap with `which` or use `match` to get the index where the value is 1.  If there is none present, return NA with `[1]` and then `coalesce` with the `diff` or `range` of 'date'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(time_to_event = as.numeric(coalesce(date[match(1,
         outcome )][1] - min(date), diff(range(date))))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 16 × 4
      id date       outcome time_to_event
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1 2013-01-01       0           730
 2     1 2014-01-01       0           730
 3     1 2015-01-01       1           730
 4     1 2016-01-01       1           730
 5     2 2013-01-01       0           365
 6     2 2014-01-01       1           365
 7     2 2015-01-01       0           365
 8     2 2016-01-01       0           365
 9     3 2013-01-01       1             0
10     3 2014-01-01       1             0
11     3 2015-01-01       0             0
12     3 2016-01-01       0             0
13     4 2013-01-01       0          1095
14     4 2014-01-01       0          1095
15     4 2015-01-01       0          1095
16     4 2016-01-01       0          1095
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I apologize that I missed a situation when a person does not have an ending event (see `id = 4` in the edited example). I tried to do the calculation with `case_when`, but it failed.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `dplyr::first`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time.to.event = first(date[outcome == 1]) - min(date))
```

```r
# Groups:   id [3]
      id date       outcome time.to.event
   <dbl> <date>       <dbl> <drtn>       
 1     1 2013-01-01       0 730 days     
 2     1 2014-01-01       0 730 days     
 3     1 2015-01-01       1 730 days     
 4     1 2016-01-01       1 730 days     
 5     2 2013-01-01       0 365 days     
 6     2 2014-01-01       1 365 days     
 7     2 2015-01-01       0 365 days     
 8     2 2016-01-01       0 365 days     
 9     3 2013-01-01       1   0 days     
10     3 2014-01-01       1   0 days     
11     3 2015-01-01       0   0 days     
12     3 2016-01-01       0   0 days
```

Comment: Thanks @Maël. I apologize that I missed a situation when a person does not have an ending event (see `id = 4` in the edited example). I tried to do the calculation with `case_when`, but it failed.